# What are some ways I can optimize this special cased closure?

Tags: swift, closures

I want to use the `sorted` method on an array.

`public func sorted(by areInIncreasingOrder: (Self.Iterator.Element, Self.Iterator.Element) -> Bool) -> [Self.Iterator.Element]`

And I can see that it takes a function (which takes 2 Elements and returns a Bool), and then returns an an array of the Element (sorted)

Where I am getting stuck, is by trying to pass an anonymous function (closure), using `$0` and `$1` as arguments

I want to add a special case, for a specific `key` **("module")**

And then I want to access a property on `$0` and `$1`

But this means, ostensibly, that I have to cast those arguments, so that I can then access the properties on those arguments

And to make things worse, because the arguments could either be `String` or `Node`, I currently have repeated code (the `switch` statement)

So anyways, do any of you Swift veterans see things that I could do to make this better?

```
return self.sorted(by: {
            for descriptor in sortDescriptors {
                if descriptor.key == "module" {
                    if let firstNode = $0 as? Node {
                        if let secondNode = $1 as? Node {
                            let firstModule = firstNode.module?.name ?? ""
                            let secondModule = secondNode.module?.name ?? ""
                            let newDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: nil, ascending: descriptor.ascending, selector: descriptor.selector)
                            switch newDescriptor.compare(firstModule, to: secondModule) {
                            case .orderedAscending:
                                return true
                            case .orderedDescending:
                                return false
                            case .orderedSame:
                                continue
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                switch descriptor.compare($0, to: $1) {
                case .orderedAscending:
                    return true
                case .orderedDescending:
                    return false
                case .orderedSame:
                    continue
                }
            }
            return false
        })
}
```

Comment: `String or Node` Are you sure you want to be combining heterogenous types in the same array? Furthermore, why are you using sort descriptors, if you're using Swift's `sorted(_:)`?

Comment: I inherited this code, with no swift background, so I'm kind of just winging it-- I added the code beyond the `if` check for `module`   But no, not going to be combining different types into one array-- it's just that the array could potentially have all `Strings` or all `Nodes`

Comment: That sounds like the job for an enum with 2 cases, one with an associated value that's a `[String]`, and another that's `[Nodes]`